# Powermail - add submission ID to email

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

Is there a variable I can add that will output a unique ID to the generated email?

Something similar to a help desk ticket ID.

I found this, but it is not 100% reliable to get a unique ID:
http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-dev/2009-December/038130.html

If not, can I generate a unique ID with typescript and feed it into the form?

Comment: Please provide detailed information regarding your requirement. so reader can give you better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(nearly) each record in TYPO3 gets an UId. I don't know whether the uid for save saved powermail data is already available in the finishers.

Otherwise timestamps normaly make good unique IDs so they are pretty large.
You might make it more unique if you append the IP, so this still will not guarrantee uniqueness.

You might create records when the empty form is called and so reserve an unique ID which gets used only if the user saves his data, but that is complicated too. (can not be done just with configuration of powermail)

Comment: I thought of a timestamp, but wouldn't it be possible for two users end up with the same timestamp?

Comment: Timestamp + IP is a great idea. One problem I've noticed is that the output of `date:U` doesn't update on refresh for a few minutes. Do you know if there is a way to get the exact time every time?

Comment: staying the same for a date hints for caches. try to use a USERINT (a help construct might be a COAINT)

Comment: Final problem: The `COA_INT` works ok in the page template but when used to prefill the powermail field it outputs `<!--INT_SCRIPT.7d6...`

Comment: That is an inidication that you use uncached content in uncached content. that String is a placeholder for the uncached content and will be replaced in a cached content, but not inside of uncached content. Are you sure your date/time does not get replaced from the server (maybe your browser caches the data)?

Comment: When I was testing I put it on the page template which required `COA_INT` but I have since found that Powermail is already uncached so I can use an ordinary `COA` when filling fields and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` into the HTML-Template. You will see every variable that you can use.

Comment: I tried adding this to the ReceiverMail template but it didn't seem to do anything?